# When my app status is background, pushkit sends a notification. How can I make the app status active?

Tags: swift, pushkit

In my app, when the app is in the background, the server sends a message to the app. This is the method called:

> func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry,
>   didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type:
>   PKPushType)

How can we make the app status active?

Answer (score 0):

You can’t. Only the user can do that, by opening your app.